# execute script on the page that will open by clicking href javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on features that infuencent web loading. I succeeded
to find a script that displays those .But my problem how to execute this script on the page that will open by clicking href

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Add load event listener.
window.addEventListener("load", loadTime, false);

function loadTime() {
    var x = performance.timing.connectEnd+"f"; 

  // Get current time.
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  // Calculate page load time.
  var page_load_time = now - performance.timing.navigationStart;
  // Write the load time to the F12 console.
  if (window.console)  { console.log(window.performance.timing);
  window.alert(x)}

}
 </script>
 <script>
 var someAnchor = document.getElementById('someAnchor');

someAnchor.onclick = function(){
  loadTime();
};

function loadTime() {
  // Get current time.
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Calculate page load time.
  var page_load_time = now - performance.timing.navigationStart;

  // Write the load time to the F12 console.
  if (window.console) {
    console.log(window.performance.timing);
  }
}
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="someAnchor" target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/">youtube</a>

</body>
</html>
```

The first script shows these carachteristics on current page but the second does not work on load youtube page

Comment: can you post your code or create a snippet?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that.

Comment: On executing this script: <script>
function loadTime() {
   
  // Get current time.
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  // Calculate page load time.
  var page_load_time = now - performance.timing.navigationStart;
  // Write the load time to the F12 console.
  if (window.console)  { console.log(window.performance.timing);
}

}
</script> I get the caracteristics of the current page.But I want to execute it on the page that will open using a href @omarCreativeDev

Comment: Edit your question and put this code there.

Answer (score 0):

so you basically just want to run your function upon clicking an anchor?

```js
var someAnchor = document.getElementById('someAnchor');

someAnchor.onclick = function(){
  loadTime();
};

function loadTime() {
  // Get current time.
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Calculate page load time.
  var page_load_time = now - performance.timing.navigationStart;

  // Write the load time to the F12 console.
  if (window.console) {
    console.log(window.performance.timing);
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="someAnchor" href="#">some anchor</a>
```

Comment: Does not work, you can test <html>
<head>

 <script>
 var someAnchor = document.getElementById('someAnchor');

someAnchor.onclick = function(){
  loadTime();
};

function loadTime() {
  // Get current time.
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Calculate page load time.
  var page_load_time = now - performance.timing.navigationStart;

  // Write the load time to the F12 console.
  if (window.console) {
    console.log(window.performance.timing);
  }
}
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="someAnchor" target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/">youtube</a>

</body>
</html>

Comment: the characteristics of the web page loading youtube will not be displayed on console but if you execute:<script type="text/javascript">
// Add load event listener.
window.addEventListener("load", loadTime, false);
function loadTime() {
    var x = performance.timing.connectEnd; 
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var page_load_time = now - performance.timing.navigationStart;
  // Write the load time to the F12 console.
  if (window.console) { console.log(window.performance.timing);
  window.alert(x)}
}</script>you will see these characteristics for the current page

Comment: do you mean you want your anchor to navigate to http://www.youtube.com and then run your function? once you navigate away from your site you wont be able to run javascript on an external site such as youtube.com.

maybe you want to look in to a browser extension to check youtube page performance.... ySlow comes to mind

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is illegal and impossible, because of security reasons, once you close a page or navogate away from it, **every** javascript function will stop immedialitely. Just imahine what would happen, if a page would navigate you back every time you leave it.